# Redux State null in render method, even after redux state is updated correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am in learning phase of react, and creating small application which fetches user wishlist from firebase table and updated redux store and I am trying to access that redux store in render method but when i console.log **this.props.wishlist** in render method its shows null. Redux state is updated correctly. Checked with redx dev tool.
[redux state screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS9eE.jpg)

Action creator which gets wishlist data from firebase API

```
export const fetchWishlist = (email)=> {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchWishlistStart());
        let rawMovieId=[];
        let uniqueMovieIdList = [];
        const queryParams ='?orderBy="email"&equalTo="'+email+'"';
        axios.get('https://movie-project-6fc34.firebaseio.com/wishlist.json'+queryParams)
        .then (response=>{
            for(let key in response.data){
                rawMovieId.push(response.data[key].movieId)
            }
            uniqueMovieIdList =  [ ...new Set(rawMovieId) ];
            dispatch(fetchMovieDetailsForWishlist(uniqueMovieIdList))   
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            console.log(error);
        }) 
    }
}

export const setMovieDetailsForWishlist = (movieDetailsList)=> {
    return {
        type:actionType.SET_MOVIEDETAILS_WISHLIST,
        movieDetailsList:movieDetailsList
    }
}

export const fetchMovieDetailsForWishlist = (movieList) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchWishlistSuccess());
        let updatedMovieList = []       
        movieList.map((currItem)=>{
            let final_api_url = api_url+movieDetails_api_end_point+currItem+api_key+'&language='+language
            axios.get(final_api_url)
            .then(response=>{
                updatedMovieList.push({
                    title:response.data.title,
                    movieId:response.data.id,
                    poster:response.data.poster_path
                })
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            })
        })
        dispatch(setMovieDetailsForWishlist(updatedMovieList));         
    }
}
```

WhislistReducer --

```
import * as actionType from '../actions/actionType.js'

const intialState =  {
    wishList:null,
    showLoader:false
}


const wishListReducer = (state=intialState, action) => {

        switch (action.type) {
            case actionType.FETCH_WISHLIST_START:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    showLoader:true
                }
            case actionType.FETCH_WISHLIST_SUCCESS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    showLoader:false
                }
            case actionType.SET_MOVIEDETAILS_WISHLIST:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    showLoader:false,
                    wishList:action.movieDetailsList
                }                       
            default:
            return state

    }
} 

export default wishListReducer;
```

wishlist component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as action from '../store/actions/index'

export class Wishlist extends Component {


    componentDidMount() {           
        this.props.fetchWishlist(window.localStorage.getItem('email'));


    render() {
        let wishListPageContent = '<div> Loading........</div>'
        let userWishlistDetails = this.props.wishlist
        console.log(userWishlistDetails);
        if (!this.props.showLoader) {
            wishListPageContent = (
            <div> wishlist component</div>

            )
        }           
        return (
            <div>
                {wishListPageContent}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {      
    return {
        userEmail:state.authState.userEmail,
        wishlist:state.wishlistState.wishList,
        isAuthSuccess:state.authState.isAuthSuccess,
        showLoader:state.wishlistState.showLoader 
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchWishlist:(email)=>dispatch(action.fetchWishlist(email)),
        fetchMovieDetailsForWishlist:(movieList)=>dispatch(action.fetchMovieDetailsForWishlist(movieList))
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Wishlist));
```

Comment: Did you correctly connected your component with `import { connect } from 'react-redux';`?

Comment: @reg yes i did, updated code for wishlist component file

Comment: Can you give the log of `action.movieDetailsList` just before you return the state in the reducer (in `case actionType.SET_MOVIEDETAILS_WISHLIST:`)? To make sure you are not actually pushing `null` to wishList.

Comment: I think it's inside `fetchMovieDetailsForWishlist` method, whats the value of final_api_url? Are you not putting a object in the string? (_currItem_)

Comment: So finally managed to solve issue. Issue was with fetchMovieDetailsForWishlist action creator. i was updating state after each api call but the correct way is to update state only once after all response is available. I used async/await and it worked perfectly fine.